# Installing Noto monospace font on Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, fonts

I installed the following packages in order to have Google's Noto fonts:

- noto-fonts
- noto-fonts-cjk
- noto-fonts-emoji

After the operation, there is a NotMono-Regular.ttf file installed in `/usr/share/fonts/noto`, but the system doesn't use it.

A quick `fc-match -s monospace` doesn't list the font.

How can I get the system to use the font?

**EDIT**

The file's permissions are 644. `fc-cache -v` returns

```
...
/usr/share/fonts/noto: skipping, existing cache is valid: 135 fonts, 0 dirs
...
```

Comment: Does the file have the correct permissions? Maybe try running `fc-cache`?

Comment: @phk I've edited the question to answer your question.

Comment: Maybe for some strange reason it's not part of the "mono" font family but I have no idea why. Apart from that the font is usable, right?